# xpath: find child, where another child of the same node has specific value

Tags: xpath

Here is the xml:

```
<cat>
    <row>
       <col attr="w">111</col>
       <col attr="p">222</col>
       <col attr="g">333</col>
       <col attr="r">444</col>
       <col attr="n1">555</col>
       <col attr="n2">666</col>
       <col attr="s">777</col>
    </row>
    <row>
       <col attr="w">aaa</col>
       <col attr="p">bbb</col>
       <col attr="g">nnn</col>
       <col attr="r">mmm</col>
       <col attr="n1">xxx</col>
       <col attr="n2">ccc</col>
       <col attr="s">vvv</col>
    </row>
</cat>
```

What I look for:
find

```
//cat/row/col[@attr='n2']
```

only , if in the same parent node

```
//cat/row/col[@attr='w']==111
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to make it more clear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an alternative solution which I consider more readable as you add the conditions in each node of the XPath expression as you go, without the need to use `parent`:

```
//cat/row[./col[@attr='w' and text()='111']]/col[@attr='n2']
```

with the same output:

```
<col attr="n2">666</col>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your correct XPATH is:

```
//cat/row/col[@attr='n2'][parent::row/col[@attr='w' and text()='111'] ]
```

to get output:

```
<col attr="n2">666</col>
```

Answer (score 0):

This xpath will find the col with attr=w and text='111', then go back to it's parent and look for the parent's children with col @attr=n2

```
//row/col[@attr='w' and text()='111']/../col[@attr='n2']
```